# My Pending changes show 13k files with "Merge" and "Merge Lock" Status and 3 Merge Edit will the all of the files will be checked in on my name

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, merge

My Pending changes show 13k files with "Merge" and "Merge Lock" Status and 3 "Merge Edit" and 2 "Merge Branch" status. Will all of the files will be checked in on my name or just the three files with "Merge Edit" and "Merge Branch.

Answer (score 0):

**All of the files will be checked in on your name**. After checked in these files, you can view the user of the changeset. It would show your user name which means this changest are triggered by you. And you can also find the number of the changes in the detais of the changest. The changes should be 13K.

In TFS, merge specifically means that its this revision contains the merge from a another branch. however,merge only represent the merge operation. So it shows **[merge]** status for the unchanged file and shows **[merge,edit]** status for the files that actually changed and shows **[merge branch]** for the new add item.